# using autocomplete jquery with zend viewmodel

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete, zend-framework2, viewmodel

This is my action function in my controller :

```
public function rescompleteAction()
{

    $name = $_POST["name"]  ;

    $data = $this->geGatwayTable("rules\Model\CandidatTable")->getCandidatByName($name);
// getCandidatByName works correctly

    if ($data) {

        $viewModel = new ViewModel(array(
            'data' => $data
        ));
        $viewModel->setTerminal(true);

        return $viewModel;
    } else 
        return null ; 
    }

}
```

My jquery function looks like these :

```
$( "#search" ).autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
            jQuery.get("/rules/public/rules/rescomplete", {
                 query: request.term
                }, function (data) {

                response(data);

         });
        },
         minLength: 3
        });
```

with google inspect element : i recive an error like these when i try to search a name :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '5855' in 

.
.
.
{ html code }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the JsonModel instead of the default ViewModel in Zend2?

Also, I dont understand your way of loading the data, could you do something like this?

`$.get( "/rules/public/rules/rescomplete", function( data ) {
       $("#search" ).autocomplete( data );
   });`